# Flask/jinjas - url_for - from pandas iterated data (itertuples)

Tags: python, pandas, flask, jinja2

Iterating over a pandas dataframe gives a HTML table.
As well as simply displaying the first column of the dataframe, I want it to be a link to the app.route(‘account’) via an  tag.

```
<table>
{% for row in df.itertuples() %}
<tr>
<td><a href="{{ url_for('account',table_name='{{ row[1] }}') }}">{{ row[1] }}</a></td>
<td>{{ row[2] }}</td>
<td>{{ row[3] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

[image]

using `table_name=‘{{ row[1] }}` isn’t working. The displayed text in the HTML output is the correct string for the `table_name` variable. (i.e. ‘Bank_Account’,’Offerings’ etc.). However using `’{{ row[1] }}’` gives something like `%7B%7B%20row%5B1%5D%20%7D%7D` rather than `Bank_Account`.

I have attempted using `{{ row[1]|safe }}`

Using the string as a text, `Bank_Account` (for example), does work for the Bank Account row, i.e. this works:

```
<td><a href="{{ url_for('account',table_name='Bank_Account') }}">{{ row[1] }}</a></td>
```

Error in the MySQL syntax, which I think is coming from wrong jinjas usage to get the `row[1]`:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{ row[1] }} ORDER BY Date' at line 1
```

app.routes

```
@app.route('/')
def trial_balance():
    data = {
        'Account': table_list,
        'Balance': Balance,
            }
    ...
    df = pandas.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Account','Balance'])
    df['Dr'] = ''
    df['Cr'] = ''
    ...
    return render_template('trial_balance.html',df=df,database=database)

@app.route('/account/<string:table_name>')
def account(table_name):
    ...
    df = pandas.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM "+table_name+" ORDER BY Date;", con=mydb)
    account = df.to_html(index=False)
    ...
    return render_template('individual_account.html',account=account,account_name=table_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you give the following code a try?

```
<td><a href="{{ url_for('account',table_name=row[1]) }}">{{ row[1] }}</a></td>
```

My understanding is when the "parser" detect curly braces, it enters "python-execution" mode. So for `{{ url_for('account',table_name=row[1]) }}` the variable `row` should already be accessible and we should treat the part in curly braces as normal python code.